# Array of HTTP Obserables to Async-Pipeable Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I'm trying to make a series of XHR GETs based on results of an initial request. I have an array of observables of the secondary requests I want to make, and I can use Array.map to iterate over them and subscribe in sequence to log all of their returned values, but I cannot understand how to format them into a flattened observable that I can print to the screen using the `async` pipe's single subscription:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // initial request - returns data on a planet
  this.planet$ = this.starWarsService.getEntityById("planets", "1");
  this.residentData$ = this.planet$.pipe(
    map(planets =>
      planets.residents.map(planet =>
        // get character data for each resident, `split` just grabs the index to construct the URL
        this.starWarsService.getEntityById("people", planet.split("/")[5])
      )
    ),
    tap(results => {
      results.map(result => {
        result.subscribe(data => {
          // this prints resident/character data correctly
          console.log("data", data);
        });
      });
    })
  );
}
```

#### How can I unwrap this array of observables into something I can unpack with a single `async` pipe?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnxb79?file=src/app/star-wars.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

you you want some like?

```
this.planet$=this.starWarsService.getEntityById("planets", "1").pipe(
  share()) //<--pipe(share()) is for only one call
this.residentData$ = this.planet$.pipe( 
  switchMap((planet:any)=>{
     //with each resident create an observable and use forkJoin
    return forkJoin(planet.residents.map(x=>
         this.starWarsService.getEntityById("people",x.split("/")[5])))
  }))
```

Comment: I'm confused why this requires the `share()`. _"//<--pipe(share()) is for only one call"_ It definitely looks like HttpClient or Angular or RxJs makes multiple calls without this. Why is that? I've put a check in `ngOnInit` to check if the `planet$` property has been set before making the API call, and it still makes multiple GETs? Do you know why?

Comment: use the tools's navigator. You can see the diference if you check the "trafic". If you don't put it, there two call to the API

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) your observables, then [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) them. The result will be an Observable, where T is the return type of your single observables.

Like this:

```
this.residentData$ = this.planet$.pipe(
  flatMap(planets => zip(...planets.residents.map(planet =>
      this.starWarsService.getEntityById("people", planet.split("/")[5])))
  ),
  tap(result => {
    console.log('result', result);
  }),
);
```